# Whathappens in isomorphism groups

Tags: group-isomorphism

Show that $$G =(\mathbb{Q}/\{-1\}{,∗), where  ∀a,b∈\mathbb{Z}}:a∗b=a+b+ab $$ forms a group and show that it is isomorphic to the group group $M=(\mathbb{Q}/\{0\},.)$ where it is the opertaion of normal multiplication.

I've already proven that G is a group but i'm having trouble to show that it is an isomorphism, because i don't seem to understand is what happens to an element from G that it transforms to M. i don't understand what happens to a single element, let's say f(x) where $x\in G$ and f is the isomorphism. wouldn't it remain the same?, or is it that th echange occurs when i do the operation of one group. but wouldn't that be hard to prove f(x*y)=f(x)·f(y)?

I would appreciate any tips

Comment: Could you rewrite your question using Latex? Also what are Q{−1} and Q{0}?

Comment: I think "$/$" should be "$\setminus$" (set difference as opposed to quotient), and "$\mathbb{Z}$" should be "$\mathbb{Q}$."

Comment: try $f(a)=a+1$ so that $f(0)=1$